# ProgrammingError at /admin/login/

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

So I changed the device I was working my Django App with. In order to change device, I just copy pasted the entire repository to the new device, setup the database, ran a fake migration and then when the app was working fine, started developing again.

However, when I started developing on the Django Admin site, I run into this problem.

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/login/
relation "django_session" does not exist

LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "django_session" WHERE "django_sessio...
```

Now, I don't know how I can access the Django Admin again. I've already checked:

1. whether the app, django admin and it's related dependencies are in the `INSTALLED APPS`. They are.
2. whether the django-admin related tables are in the database: they are.
3. Checked whether I've registered the models to the Admin Site in `admin.py`. I have.
4. Whether I did a correct fake migration. I ran `python manage.py makemigrations`, and it told me `No changes detected.` I ran migrate, told me no migrations to apply. I even looked at `showmigrations` and it already applied all the migrations to the admin site.

The one thing I haven't tried, and I would prefer not to do it, is to delete all the migration files and start from scratch. Would appreciate any help and I've searched high and low for a similar problem in SO

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn’t have faked the migrations if you had a new database. This marks the migrations as done, but doesn’t actually run them.

That means Django thinks it has run the migration to create the sessions table (no migrations detected) but it hasn’t actually created it (relation does not exist).

If you faked all the migrations, you can probably get it to work by deleting the entries from the `django_migrations` table and running migrate properly. Otherwise, it might be easiest to recreate the database if it doesn’t contain any important data.

Comment: I'm not actually using a "new" database. I just backed up the database from the previous machine, and then restored it into the current machine. 

or should I still run a proper migration for that?

Comment: You didn’t do a full backup, otherwise the `django_session` table would be in your database. If the some tables exist in your database and you try to run those migrations without fake, then you’ll get different errors. Getting migrations and your database schema back in sync can be very tricky. There’s not enough info in your question to know what the differences are, and even if you add it, you might not find anyone on Stack Overflow willing to figure out the exact commands to get it back in sync.